# How to split data with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, port

I created a script with Python to read data from a serial port. But I'm stuck with the split part. I'm new with this programming language.

I would like to save the parameters inside variables.

```
import serial 
import re
from serial import Serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
print(ser.isOpen) #True
serial_data = ser.readline()
print(serial_data)
```

**Output**: b' H:209.44 R:4.88 P:-168.00 A:1 M0 G3 S:0 T:0.00\r\n

```
encoding = serial_data.decode(encoding = "ascii", errors = "ignore")

encoding_split = encoding.split(" ")
```

**Output**:['', 'H:209.44', 'R:4.88', 'P:-168.00', 'A:1', 'M0', 'G3', 'S:0', 'T:0.00\r\n']

Wrong part: Now I would like to save the values inside a variables

```
H =(re.search(r'(?<=H:)\w+', encoding_split)
R =(re.search(r'(?<=R:)\w+', encoding_split)
P =(re.search(r'(?<=P:)\w+', encoding_split)
A =(re.search(r'(?<=A:)\w+', encoding_split)
M =(re.search(r'(?<=M)\w+',  encoding_split)
G =(re.search(r'(?<=G)\w+',  encoding_split)
S =(re.search(r'(?<=S:)\w+', encoding_split)
T =(re.search(r'(?<=T:)\w+', encoding_split)
```

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do now ?? Your question and the error inside are different ?  can you just print the ```type()``` of a variable

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re.search#re.search). `re.search` works on _strings_, not lists.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks, really. 

I'm still stuck but I made some improvement :D

H = encoding_string[1]

Output H:209.4 --> Now I will like to remove the 'H:' part from my element

Comment: @sgsg, great! You can just remove the first two elements of each string with `H = H[2:]`. For M and G, remove the first (one) element.

Comment: @ForceBru I edit the question, thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
# serial_data contains the data in binary format
serial_data =  b' H:209.44 R:4.88 P:-168.00 A:1 M0 G3 S:0 T:0.00\r\n'

# We convert byte data to string as below
serial_data_string = serial_data.decode('utf-8')

# We remove white space from both ends
serial_data_string = serial_data_string.strip()

# Convert the string to array having pair of Key and value
paired_data = serial_data_string.split(' ')

# We Create a dict to store the ouput
output = {}

# We iterate over each item in array and extract key and value
# and set the to dict

for each_key_value_pair in paired_data:
    key_value_splitted = each_key_value_pair.split(':')
    key = key_value_splitted[0]
    value = 0
    if len(key_value_splitted) > 1:
        value = float(key_value_splitted[1])

    # We set this value to ouput variable

    output[key] = value


print(output)

# Now you can access outputs like 
A = output['A']
B = output['R']
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks :) Really appreciated the help of everyone <3

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the RegEx, I think.

I gave a try, please have a look

```
import serial
import re
from serial import Serial

def main():
    # ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
    # print(ser.isOpen) #True
    # serial_data = ser.readline()
    # print(serial_data)
    # encoding = serial_data.decode(encoding = "ascii", errors = "ignore")
    # encoding_split = encoding.split(" ")
    encoding_split="H:209.44', 'R:4.88', 'P:-168.00', 'A:1', 'M0', 'G3', 'S:0', 'T:0.00\r\n"
    H=(re.search(r"(?<=H:)(\-*\s*[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)", encoding_split))
    R=(re.search(r"(?<=R:)(\-*\s*[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)", encoding_split))
    P=(re.search(r"(?<=P:)(\-*\s*[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)", encoding_split))
    A=(re.search(r"(?<=A:)(\-*\s*[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)", encoding_split))
    M=(re.search(r"(?<=M)(\-*\s*[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)",  encoding_split))
    G=(re.search(r"(?<=G)(\-*\s*[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)",  encoding_split))
    S=(re.search(r"(?<=S:)(\-*\s*[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)", encoding_split))
    T=(re.search(r"(?<=T:)(\-*\s*[0-9]+\.*[0-9]*)", encoding_split))

    print(H.group(0))
    print(R.group(0))
    print(P.group(0))
    print(A.group(0))
    print(M.group(0))
    print(G.group(0))
    print(S.group(0))
    print(T.group(0))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```